# setting a date and time within a banner to say we are open or closed

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to input a "We are open" text in the long banner on my website.

And "We are closed" between the other hours. That would mainly be 12-6pm every day apart from saturday which is 10:00-6pm.

How should I go about this?

Comment: on page load or without loading? In php or Javascript?

Comment: A simple PHP function that outputs "open" or "closed" depending on the current time would be enough. You could overlay a div on top of the banner with an echo of the function output would display the appropriate message depending on the time it was when the page was loaded

Comment: I tried to make your question a bit more clear, please review my changes. But then: your question is really too broad. Do you want to use java script or php? So only use ONE language tag. Then: you should do some research on your own. I am sure that "fetching the current time", and doing an if/then/else is a very basic and easy thing in any language. Don't expect people here to *teach* you things that can be found on page 2 of any good book or tutorial!

Answer (score 0):

Get time date now(current time) assign it to a variable then use if statements to compare the value to your conditions once that is done change the inner HTML of the banner depending on the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

This is the php script you need, then for the UI side you should take care, not having specified in your question what are you using or any piece of code. This script checks the day of the week and the time:

```
$now = date("H");
$day = date("w");

if(($day != 6 && $now >= 12 && $now < 18) 
    || ($day == 6 && $now >= 10 && $now < 18))
{
    $status = "open";
}
else
{
    $status = "closed";
}
```

You may then want to work with the UTC date values to avoid issues if people access your website outside the timezone where your country is.

Answer (score 0):

js script which checks multiple days and office hours.

```
var d = new Date();
if (d.getDay() !== 7) {
    if (d.getDay() !== 6) {
        if (d.getHours() >= 12 && d.getHours() <= 18) {
            // office hours during the week
        } else {
            // closed during the week
        }
    } else {
        if (d.getHours() >= 10 && d.getHours() <= 18) {
            // office hours on saturday
        } else {
            // closed on saturday
        }
    }
} else {
    // code for when its sunday.
}
```

Remove the `if (d.getDay() !==7){}` if the office hours on Sunday are the same as week days.